# electron.js print functionality with page size, dpi ,layout, margin settings from main process

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, electron

I need to take printout of electron screen with default setting for parameters like page size, dpi ,layout, margin settings etc as set from electron main process. while as per electron print api documentation it only support options for  silent, printBackground and deviceName. Any workaround to set default options from electron itself rather than opening a OS specific print preference window.

Even DOM window object print function also not support default setting.

Reference links for electron print api
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback

DOM print API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

Thanks